# Create white page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

Can I create a total white page in my wordpress site. This site have a theme but I'd like to create 1 white page for copy shortcode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new template file. Do this:

1) Create one php file, like: white_page.php inside your themes folder;

2) In this file, put this code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: White Page */ ?>
```

3) Go to your Wordpress admin and create one page, like: White Page

4) Set in this page your new template, [like that](https://postimg.org/image/gm4vtedrf/)

5) After publish, you will have your white page. Just get the page permalink.

Comment: [ai1ec] for plug-in time.ly.

Comment: I'm trying with `
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
` 
but if I delete header the css are not ok

Comment: Your code look incomplete. All the code in the page [looks like this](https://postimg.org/image/t5bfp16bn/). Note: If you run the function `do_shortcode` inside the `template_part content_page`, you don't need to add again.

Comment: It's ok with this: 

'<?php
/**
 * Template Name: daterracina Page Template
 *
 * Displays the...
 *
 */
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[ai1ec cat_name="Terracina > Ponza"]' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>'

but without footer the css are not ok. Can I delete or hide and see correct css? Thanks

Comment: You forget the `get_header()` function. [See a reference](https://postimg.org/image/kxbg858jv/). You must add `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions to CSS and JS works in the custom template. See this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) that teaches you how to work with custom templates.